# Get response from the web service for HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, web-services, httpresponse, image-uploading

In my application, the User can upload images to a PHP server, the iOS version is working 100%, the Android version used for this tutorial to upload image:
[tutorial example](http://costimuraru.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/android-upload-image-to-a-site-with-a-post-method/)

And the function I'm using is this:

```
public static String sendPost(String url, String imagePath) 
        throws IOException, ClientProtocolException  {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    File file = new File(imagePath);

    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);

    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    //Log.e("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    //Log.e(""+response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
        //Log.e(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return response.toString();

}
```

> return response.toString(); get it in org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse @ 406dc148

But the return of the web service is the URL where the image was saved, I need to have a string in the return of the PHP server, rather than the return I mentioned above how can I have it?

I wanted something like this (HttpURLConnection):
HttpURLConnection conn;
...

```
String response= "";
Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

while(inStream.hasNextLine())
    response+=(inStream.nextLine());
Log.e("resp", response);
```

After one hour onsegui trying to get the response from the Web service as follows:
...

```
byte [] responseBody = httppost.getMethod().getBytes(); 
Log.e("RESPONSE BODY",""+(new String(responseBody)));
```

...

Comment: see javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpResponse.html

Comment: I looked at the documentation however not found something where I could get the return of my web service, the return is something like <?php echo $urlImage ?>, edited the post, look for an example that works

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content returned by the HTTP server, you shouldn't do this:

```
if (resEntity != null) {
    resEntity.consumeContent();
}
```

... because that says "throw away the content".

Comment: it did not return the response WebService which case it is the path (URL) to which the image was moved at the time of upload, the case solved as follows:   byte [] responseBody = httppost.getMethod().getBytes(); 
 Log.e("RESPONSE BODY",""+(new String(responseBody)));

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the response is of type String

```
  ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post, new BasicHttpContext()); // new BasicHttpContext() not necessary 
// verify connection response status using httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() then

  String response =  responseHandler.handleResponse(httpResponse);
  if(response != mull){
     Log.e("Response : "+response);
  }else{
   // Handle exception 
  }
 return response;
```